# Build mediapipe on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: kubuntu, python

I'm trying to build MediaPipe from source with Bazel on Linux ubuntu 22.04. here are the full steps ive done so far:

```
1. git clone https://github.com/google/mediapipe.git
2. cd mediapipe
3. bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1   mediapipe/examples/desktop/desktop/holistic_tracking:holistic_tracking_cpu
```

but it's always failing with the following error:

```
In file included from ./mediapipe/util/annotation_renderer.h:20,
                 from mediapipe/util/annotation_renderer.cc:15:
./mediapipe/framework/port/opencv_core_inc.h:18:10: fatal error: opencv2/core/version.hpp: No such file or directory
   18 | #include <opencv2/core/version.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/holistic_tracking:holistic_tracking_cpu failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.284s, Critical Path: 0.88s
INFO: 110 processes: 101 internal, 9 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I tried to build opencv from source with cmake and it worked, the absolute path for it is

```
  /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2
```

but for some reason, Bazel is unable to find it even though I tried to manually add the full path in WORKSPACE, BUILD.bazel files.

I have been stuck with this error for about a week now, does anyone have a stable solution for this?

Comment: Does `locate version.hpp` find the file? What does a `ls -l opencv2/core/version.hpp`, issued from the build directory, reveal?

Comment: **localte version.hpp:**
`/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/version.hpp
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/dnn/version.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/version.hpp
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/dnn/version.hpp`
**ls -l opencv2/core/version.hpp:**
`ls: cannot access 'opencv2/core/version.hpp': No such file or directory`

Comment: So are you issuing the command from the wrong directory? What does `pwd` reveal?

Comment: no, my issue is that bazel is unable to find opencv2 directory that is found in /usr/local/include/opencv4, which is required to build Mediapipe.
I don't know why or I don't know where to edit if I have to (absolute/relative path) 
and that is my problem.

Comment: does your workspace file not contain a tag to the location of opencv2?

Comment: it does have the following:

`http_archive(
    name = "opencv",
    build_file_content = all_content,
    strip_prefix = "opencv-3.4.10",
    urls = ["https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.10.tar.gz"],
)

new_local_repository(
    name = "linux_opencv",
    build_file = "@//third_party:opencv_linux.BUILD",
    path = "/usr",
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually solved by following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/install.md), but for opencv setup I went with option 2 (setup_opencv.sh)